# flutter build appbundle faild

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I Tried to build a appbundle bundle every time with the same error.
Any ideas?

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> Failed to read key upload from store "/Users/xammex/Programmieren/Dev/organizer/android/app/upload-keystore.jks": Integrity check failed: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

Try to generate the key again with this additional attribute (It is required for Java 9 or newer):

```
-storetype JKS
```

So, the whole line become:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore ~/upload-keystore.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias upload -storetype JKS
```

After that, you can link this key with the key.properties and build the appbundle again and it will be successful.

Comment: yes, it worked yeehaaa thanks a lot

Comment: @Xammex Awesome, can you mark the reply as useful and mark it as the answer for the question?